# gsutil always attempts to upload same file on startup and fails on larger file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Whenever I attempt to `gsutil rsync` my folder, it uploads the same file (an mp4) first, then continues with the rest of the rsync -- as if that file is continuously changing (it isn't).

It also seems to have trouble with larger files

One folder I have contains iso images of linux, and one of them keeps failing with a `"ResumableUploadException"`

I've tried with/without specifying thread and parallel processes and using/not using composite uploads. With composite upload, it gets to the last segment and keeps failing that one.

Anyone know why either of these two issues is happening?

Comment: Does the behavior with the mp4 file happens too with any other mp4 file you have? How large is the image of linux? and is there any file bigger than this one that doesn't show up this error?

Comment: The MP4 is only 6M and other MP4s (and flacs which are generally bigger) upload successfully. The iso image in question is 7G. Mind you -- these both have eastern (Japanese/Chinese) characters and I know these often cause problems to badly written applications.

Comment: I think it's better to post this to [Google's Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) in case it's a misbehavior of the gsutil tool.

Comment: Thanks, @Neri , I'll do that and post back here when I get an update